# Compilar no seu computador realmente melhora a performance?

Tags: c, c++, otimização

Qualquer programador sabe que quando se compila um C/C++, o compilador pode otimizar o código para gerar executáveis mais rápidos. Mas, também é dito por aí que existe a otimização do compilador para seu processador.

Isso significa que se eu criei um programa em C e o compilei num desktop com um Intel Core i3, o programa está otimizado para rodar com máxima performance no Intel Core i3 mas rodará normalmente em outros processadores x86_64. Eu não sei se isso é verdade, só dizendo.

Com base nisso, eu vejo muito dizer por aí que a melhor forma de ter um programa rodando com a máxima eficiência no seu computador é instalá-lo direto do código-fonte. Tanto que alguns entusiastas do Gentoo Linux fazem uso dessa ideia para dizer que o Gentoo Linux é a distribuição mais rápida do planeta (Gentoo é uma distribuição onde tudo é instalado direto do código-fonte, do kernel aos aplicativos mais básicos).

Mas, eu estou desconfiando de tudo isso. Essa conversa de que algo compilado no seu computador vai rodar com a máxima performance nele é real? E, acrescentando: O fato do Gentoo Linux ser uma distribuição onde tudo é instalado direto do código-fonte realmente faz dele um sistema que tem uma performance notável?

Answer (score 12):

O fato é que quando você compila um código com o seu compilador, por padrão ele assume que você quer distribuir o executável para outras pessoas. Então por mais que ele otimize, o código precisa continuar rodando em qualquer processador popular que esteja no mercado. Assim o compilador não pode simplesmente usar instruções muito avançadas como vetorização e afins.

Para melhorar a performance nesse caso existem duas opções do GCC bastante interessantes:

- **`-march=`**`cpu-type`

  Define o mínimo que o compilador deve assumir sobre a CPU. Se você expecificar uma que suporta instruções AVX por exemplo, o compilador vai usar elas livremente sem se preocupar com o código não funcionar em processadores anteriores. O legal é que você pode escrever assim: `-march=native` e a otimização será baseada no processador da **sua** máquina. Se o código é para ser executado somente por você, use essa flag. Não esquecendo é claro das outras opções de otimização como `-O3` e `-fomit-frame-pointer`.
- **`-mtune=`**`cpu-type`

  Essa opção é parecida. O compilador vai gerar código otimizado para aquele modelo em específico, mas ele também gera condicionais para checar se as funcionalidades estão realmente presentes no processador e inclui implementações alternativas. Na prática o código fica maior, mas roda em qualquer processador e tem performance comparável ao `-march` no processador alvo.

  ```
  if (cpu suporta AVX)
      ComputeComAVX();
  else if (cpu suporta SSE2)
      ComputeComSSE2();
  else
      ComputeGenerico();
  ```

Para o GCC 4.9.0, você pode encontrar aqui a lista de processadores suportados e outras flags relevantes, como a `-mavx` para indicar que pode usar AVX.

[**3.17.17 Intel 386 and AMD x86-64 Options**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html)

Na minha maquina a arquitetura usada por padrão é a i686 (Pentium Pro) de 1995. Então sem dúvida alguma há uma melhora significativa de performance, especialmente em código que possa ser vetorizado.

Comment: Interessante. Mas a opção -O3 não é perigosa porque corre o perigo do compilador mudar o comportamento do programa?

Comment: @Sid Para programas que não estejam cheios de ***undefined behaviour*** e afins, não. Nenhuma otimização muda o comportamento de código bem definido. Se você precisa trocar de opção para o seu código funcionar, tem algo de errado com o código e não com a opção ;)

Comment: Então acho que jogar -O3 no arquivo do Gentoo da qual eu não lembro o nome, um arquivo que configura flags globais por compilador não é recomendável. Compilando coisas direto do código-fonte vejo milhares de warnings de variáveis não usadas, funções depreciadas, etc. Mas, e o papo de que o Gentoo é a distribuição mais rápida que existe porque é toda feita do código-fonte, é verdade?

Comment: @Sid Se estiver compilando com `-march=native` o ganho de performance é de uns 30%, em geral. Mas se lembre que para dizer se é mais rápido ou não precisa comparecer laranjas com laranjas. O Geento vai ser mais rapido que alguma outra distribuição que use os mesmos pacotes nas mesmas versões. Quando começa a comparar bananas com maçãs nada disso faz sentido. Sobre otimização quebrar uma biblioteca, eu consideraria isso um bug.

Comment: Não, acho que não seria bug porque isso tem a premissa de que os desenvolvedores do produto estão 100% preocupados com a qualidade do código, o que não é bem assim. Se fosse, eu não veria milhares de warnings enquanto compilo o Mate. Além do mais, o fato da biblioteca estar por aí não significa que ela está boa, OpenSSL que o diga. Já viu o código daquela aberração?

Comment: Bom, então acho que a resposta é que a otimização específica só para o seu computador existe, não é? Mas não por padrão, exige flags.

Comment: @Sid Eu considero um bug, mas é provável que eles marquem como WONTFIX. Ai vai de biblioteca para biblioteca. Os caras da glibc mesmo, afirmam que é impossível fazer uma libc sem warnings... Sobre a otimização, sim. Se apenas compilar sem mexer nas flags (provavelmente o Gentoo o faz) não obter nada melhor que um binário genérico baixado da internet. Mas também convém ligar alguma otimização, caso contrário nem haverá como o compilador se aproveitar das instruções mais recentes. Ao menos `-ftree-vectorize`.

Comment: Vendo tudo isso, me pergunto qual é a desse Gentoo: Se otimização estática só está disponível através de flags, qual a utilidade de criar um sistema da qual você gasta horas e horas compilando seus aplicativos para ter um SO completo e no final das contas o resultado será o mesmo de uma distribuição com binários genéricos? - Sendo assim, penso em nem experimentar o Gentoo.

Comment: @Sid Ora, o Gentoo usa essas flags, se não nada faria sentido.